# Attach Excel file to email

Tags: javascript, excel, cordova, email-attachments

I am currently using [email](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer) plugin to send email and am able to send HTML content and attach files like images, by attaching imageUri. I have some table data (text) which I intend to send in an attachment (.xls).

Can anyone guide me which MIME type/Content-type I have to use?

I have tried `application/excel`, `data:application/vnd.ms-excel`but attachment format is not supported.

My table data is

```
var mime = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
var table_html="<table><tr><td>r1</td><td>c2</td></tr><tr><td>r2</td><td>c2</td></tr></table>";
```

Comment: Perhaps try: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet? This is the type I use for having blobs download as .xlsx

Comment: Still I am getting attachment format is not supported.

Comment: What gives you that error?

Comment: A toast given by gmail